# How can I check Red line metro schedules in Washington DC 3, 4 days in advance to plan a trip?

Tags: trains, washington-dc, timetables

Is there a mobile app or any other way that I can check metro schedules in advance?

Comment: downvoted for missing research effort

Comment: I checked their website but it does not allow me to check schedules in advance. Trip planner only gives me the next available metro and there was no way to check metro schedule 3, 4 days in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There will not be any trains at those hours. [The rail hours](https://www.wmata.com/service/rail/) are:

> Monday - Thursday     5 am - 11:30 pm
>
> Friday    5 am - 1 am
>
> Saturday  7 am - 1 am
>
> Sunday    8 am - 11 pm

You can use their [Trip Planner](https://www.wmata.com/schedules/trip-planner/) to get specific schedule information for a journey, the real-time departure information on [the WMATA website](https://www.wmata.com/) (next bus/next train), [the live train map](https://gis.wmata.com/metrotrain/index.html), or any number of [third-party transit apps](https://dc.curbed.com/2016/1/29/10872174/best-dc-metro-android-iphone-apps-free-metrohero-bustrackdc-dc-metro) for information. [The timetables page](https://www.wmata.com/schedules/timetables/) (switch to the "rail" tab) lists service hours and will tell you the when to catch the first and last trains from any given station ("Station Service Hours"). As WMATA is doing a lot of maintenance and reconstruction, be sure to check [the service alerts](https://www.wmata.com/service/status/index.cfm) for changes that may impact your trip.

The trip planner or Google Maps can be used to plan out alternate routes for late-night journeys, but a taxi, Uber, or Lyft may be the best option or only option in many cases.

Comment: Yes, I saw this here - https://www.wmata.com/schedules/timetables/ as well. I guess Friday 5am - 1am means  5am Friday to 1am on Saturday. Non of these sites gives 3, 4 days advance schedules of metro time table. I want to plan a small trip in advance and wanted to know the earliest metro available on weekends

Comment: @Mad then check the "Station Service Hours" to see the earliest train at the stations you're interested in. You can even live chat them (when it's not a holiday weekend) or call them up and they'll give you personalized trip planning help.